# Flutter not picking up android device

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and dart. I am wotking on a project and I want to run it on android device. I am using android studio as IDE. I have conected an android device I have **developer options and USB debugging on**. android studio is showing it but **not in flutter connected devices**. I also tried VS code but **VS code is also not showing the device**. I have attached an image file here as well

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxCJb.png)

Can you guys help me solve this issue?

Comment: If the device is not recognized in several IDEs, it doesn't seem to be an IDE problem, but rather a device problem. Are you sure that the port you are connecting your device to/cable are valid?

Comment: Run `adb devices` in a terminal. What does it return?

Comment: You may be missing something. Check it out here: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options  Did you clicked `Trust this computer` on the phone?